# extract specific data from a group of json-files

Tags: json, excel, csv, export, extract

Disclaimer: I know similar questions have been asked and answered before, but as a layperson I was not able to understand some terminology and what I need to do or which programme/software I should use. I would be very grateful if someone would be so kind as to explain it in a way that it is easy to understand, with clear steps if possible. I am trying to learn how to analyse and extract data with my computer, but I have only just started a few weeks ago and am still very new at this. Thank you!

I have a a large collection of json-files (several thousands) each containing metadata about a singular online post, such as the post-ID, the username (and full name, if made public by the user), timestamp and so on. I would like to extract this information from each file without having to do so manually, but am myself not yet familiar enough with my command line, Python or R (or something else that might work) to figure out how I can do this. I would like to export this data as one Excel- or csv-file in which each row contains all extracted data of one post and each column contains one type of extracted data.

Another problem I have is that some of the files will contain several sets of different data with the same name when someone commented on the post. However, I only need this information about the main post (thus the first time this information appears in the file).

(Part of) The information in the file looks like this (all personal information has been exchanged for neutral stand-in information):

```
"fact_check_information": null,
        "fact_check_overall_rating": null,
        "gating_info": null,
        "has_ranked_comments": false,
        "id": "***0000000000000000000***",
        "is_ad": false,
        "is_video": false,
        "location": null,
        "media_preview": "xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "owner": {
            "blocked_by_viewer": false,
            "followed_by_viewer": false,
            "full_name": "***Jane Doe***",
            "has_blocked_viewer": false,
            "id": "000000000",
            "is_private": false,
            "is_unpublished": false,
            "is_verified": false,
            "profile_pic_url": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "requested_by_viewer": false,
            "username": "***janedoe***"
        },
        "shortcode": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "taken_at_timestamp": ***0000000000***,
        "thumbnail_resources": [
```

I added three asterisks around the informtion I wish to extract.

Does anyone have any idea how I might be able to extract and export this information? 
Thank you so much in advance!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install mongodb... import the json and export csv... mongodb will create a table essentially from any json data. For nested dictionaries it creates nested linked tables. So double click on the structure you want to expand more and export only that inner table to csv.